Combining `\addplot3` Commands with Separate Colors in PGFPlots
I'm trying to combine all \addplot3 commands into one while maintaining separate colors for different y domains in PGFPlots. Here is the code I have so far:
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{uniblack}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes.geometric, 3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
 \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=none,
        view={140}{25},
        axis equal,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0:1.25,
        xmax=1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0, zmax=1.5,
        ticks=none,
        clip bounding box=upper bound
      ]
    
      % Plot the entire surface in red
      \addplot3 [
        surf, 
        shader=flat,
        draw=red!50!uniblack,
        fill=blue!10!white,
        z buffer=sort,
        samples=25, % Reduced samples for efficiency
        samples y=10,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0:1.25,
        restrict z to domain=-1.5:1.5,
      ] 
      ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
      
      % Fill the area from y = 0.6 to 1.25 with gray color
      \addplot3 [
        surf, 
        shader=flat,
        draw=gray!50!black,
        fill=gray!30,
        z buffer=sort,
        samples=25, % Reduced samples for efficiency
        samples y=10,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0.0:0.6,
        restrict z to domain=-1.5:1.5,
      ] 
      ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
        
       % Plot the middle part with blue color
      \addplot3 [
        surf, 
        shader=flat,
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!30,
        z buffer=sort,
        samples=25, % Reduced samples for efficiency
        samples y=5,
        domain=0:60,
        y domain=0.4025:0.6, % Only the middle circle
        restrict z to domain=-1.5:1.5,
      ] 
      ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
         
      \foreach \i in {-75,-70,...,140} {
      \addplot3 [
        thick,
        draw=uniblack,
        samples=2, % Small segments
        domain=\i:\i+4.9, % Small segments with a tiny gap
      ] 
      ({sin(x)*0.6}, {cos(x)*0.6}, {(0.6^2-1)^2});
    }

    \end{axis}  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Result:

I want to combine these \addplot3 commands into one, so that the surface is gray for y values from 0.0 to 0.6 and blue white for y values from 0.65 to 1.25 and so on. However, I haven't been able to achieve this.
I've tried using the patch option with a custom colormap, but it didn't work as expected. Here is an example of what I tried to combine the two first àdplot3`
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3 [
      patch, 
      shader=flat,
      draw=mapped color,
      fill=mapped color,
      z buffer=sort,
      samples=25, % Reduced samples for efficiency
      samples y=10,
      domain=0:360,
      y domain=0:1.25,
      restrict z to domain=-1.5:1.5,
      colormap={mycolormap}{%
        color(0cm)=(gray!30); 
        color(0.6cm)=(gray!30); 
        color(0.61cm)=(blue!10!white); 
        color(1.25cm)=(blue!10!white)
      }
    ] 
    ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});

%the rest of the code

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This resulted in errors related to the colormap definition. How can I combine these two \addplot3 commands into one while maintaining the separate colors for different y domains?

Do not use restrict z to domain unless you know what it does. You might want to set zmin and zmax.

You have syntax errors in your colormap.
There is a bug in PGFPlots when using z buffer=sort combined with a non-uniform colormap.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted,
%colormap={mycolormap}{color(0)=(gray!30) color(0.6)=(gray!30) color(0.61)=(blue!10!white) color(1.25)=(blue!10!white)},
z buffer=sort,
samples=25, samples y=10,
domain=0:360, y domain=0:1.25,
] 
({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Without color map:

Without z-buffer sort

It is not possible to have both activated at the same time. An obvious and simple solution for this problem is just to make two \addplots.
Edit: With two \addplot, but no longer compile-time
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted,
gray!30, faceted color=gray!30!white!80!black,
z buffer=sort,
samples=25, samples y=6,
domain=0:360, y domain=0.6:1.25,
] ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted,
blue!10!white, faceted color=blue!10!white!80!black,
z buffer=sort,
samples=25, samples y=5,
domain=0:360, y domain=0:0.6,
]  ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thank you for your guidance.
I reached this conclusion myself, but as a beginner, I thought there might be an optimized way to combine the four \addplot3 commands into one. In the tikzpicture, there are other figures that I haven't posted here, which together make the compile time very slow. I hope someone can find a trick or method to combine them into one.

The compile time is dependent on the number of points in the plots. Splitting one plot into two plots with different domains and half the samples(dependent on domain size) will not take longer.

I understand the time complexity aspect. That’s why I commented in the first code near the sample number with “% Reduced samples for efficiency.” I couldn’t reduce the sample number further. Additionally, some of the other figures I mentioned in my last comment are directly connected to the figure illustrated above. Therefore, it’s very difficult to implement your suggestion about splitting the connected figures into two parts.

I do not understand. I have made an edit and added the plot as I would do it. I have no further insight.
